# Win32 C++ repaint the window

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface

I've read quite a bit about the subject, but either

A. I'm not quite sure how to use the solution, or 
B. The solution doesn't work.

For the sake of my own learning, I'm trying to make a draggable box in a C++ window.  I originally draw the rectangle through the `WM_PAINT` message in `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    DrawRect(hdc, 0, 0, width, 20, RGB(60, 60, 60));

    DrawRect(hdc, boxx, boxy, boxx + 100, boxy + 20, RGB(0, 100, 255));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

I'm pretty sure my DrawRect function is working just fine, as it does draw the box.

To make the box draggable, I placed a method, I first define the point of the cursor relative to the window:

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = ((int)(short)LOWORD(lParam));
pt.y = ((int)(short)HIWORD(lParam));
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
```

Then, in the message WM_LBUTTONDOWN: I set the box x and y coordinates:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    boxx = pt.x;
    boxy = pt.y;
    break;
```

Although this does set the box x and y coordinates, I've come to realize that the window never attempts to draw the box again.  So to fix this problem, I tried to add `InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, NULL);` to my code, to no avail.

So my question persists, how do I get the program to redraw or repaint the window?

EDIT: I have changed my code to handle both `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` like so:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    boxdragmode = true;
    break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if(boxdragmode)
    {
        boxx = pt.x;
        boxy = pt.y;
    }
    break;
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    boxdragmode = false;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
    break;
```

It still doesn't update the window, or it might not update the box coordinates.  I get the coordinates through this:

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = ((int)(short)LOWORD(lParam));
pt.y = ((int)(short)HIWORD(lParam));
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you handling `WM_MOUSEMOVE` as well, to track the actual dragging?  And `WM_LBUTTONUP` to stop dragging when the button is released? `InvalidateRect` is the right way to force a re-paint of your window, but you need to do it in response to the right inputs.

Comment: No, i have not handled either of those.  My log for this is, it doesn't matter when it's moved or released, if the button is down, it want it to set the window to that location

Comment: It still doesn't work....

Comment: It looks like you're only setting the value of `pt` once, from `lParam` - but in response to which message? `lParam` only contains the mouse coordinates when it's a mouse message. You should be updating `pt` every time you get `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

Comment: I update pt every time I receive _a_ message.

Comment: Update pt only for the mouse messages. And where are boxx and boxy defined? They need to be outside of the wndproc or they will not persist until the next message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me when I try it using basically the code as you've written it. A couple of things, though. It's not clear where you're setting the POINT value. You don't really need to bother, though. Include windowsx.h and use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM`.

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    boxdragmode = true;
    break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if(boxdragmode)
    {
        boxx = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        boxy = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    }
    break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    boxdragmode = false;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);
    break;
```

You don't need to call `ScreenToClient`, because the mouse coordinates from a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, or `WM_LBUTTONUP` message are already in client coordinates. As long as `boxdragmode`, `boxx`, and `boxy` are defined so that they will persist between `WndProc` calls, that will work. However, because you don't invalidate the client area until `WM_LBUTTONUP` the box won't drag with the mouse. It will just draw when you let go.

Comment: A ha! So apparently, when I called `case WM_NCHITTEST:` and returned `HTCAPTION` if it was in the title bar, I was supposed to return `HTCLIENT` otherwise.  Which leads me to my next question.  When I questioned the coordinates of the click in `WM_NCHITTEST`, I had to do `ScreenToClient(hWnd, &ps)` otherwise it didn't work correctly.

Why is it that `WM_NCHITTEST` requires `ScreenToClient` however any other message doesn't?

Comment: The `WM_NC*` mouse messages (like `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`) all give screen coordinates, too. The "NC" part stands for non-client. It wouldn't make much sense to give non-client information in client coordinates.

Comment: Joel - Thank you very much.  That was _extremely_ helpful.  

Jonathan - That was not helpful.